# Print the contents of Python3 list element instead of value

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list inside Python3 with two variables that contain values that are set via argparse:

```
start = set by user cli argument 
end = set by user cli argument

arguments=[start,end]

print (arguments[0])
print (arguments[1])
```

This currently just gives the integer values of start and end that the user set via the command line, but I would also like to print the variable names. How can I do this? Ultimately I am attempting to check to see if the variable has been set by the user via the cli. I have a for loop to iterate through all the available arguments the user may set.

```
arguments=[start,end]
print (arguments[0]) //This (test) returns the integer the user set
print (arguments[1]) //This (test) returns the integer the user set

for x in arguments:
    if results.arguments[x] is not None: //results.start and results.end are the variables coming from argparse
        print ('User has set argument values via the CLI... Do something here.') //This is where I would actually use the integer value of arguments[x], but above in the if statement, I need the variable string from the array element.
    else:
        print ('User did not specify any arguments via the CLI. Pull the values from the config file.')
```

** EXAMPLE **

```
user@taco# python3 program.py -s 100 -e 1000
```

The user runs the program and specifies a starting value of 100 and an ending value of 1000

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Taco help menu', add_help=True)
parser.add_argument('-s', '--start', dest='start', action='store', help='enter the starting <value>', metavar='<value>')
parser.add_argument('-e', '--end', dest='end', action='store', help='enter the ending <value>', metavar='<value>')
results = parser.parse_args()

arguments=[start,end]
```

Lets check where we're at with some print commands

```
print (arguments[0]) // Should output 100
print (arguments[1]) // Should output 1000
print (results.start) // Should also output 100
print (results.end) // Should also output 1000
```

Now we need to check if the user has set the arguments. To do that lets check if results.start and results.end are set not None. We need a for loop though to iterate through all possible arguments. Currently there are just two (start and end), but who knows, there may be more later.

```
for x in arguments:
    if results.arguments[x] is not None:
        print ('User has set argument values via the CLI... Do something here.') //This is where I would actually use the integer value of arguments[x], but above in the if statement, I need the variable string from the array element.
    else:
        print ('User did not specify any arguments via the CLI. Pull the values from the config file.')
```

*** UPDATE ***

Ok, I made a bit more progress and was confusing a few things. I think I have it narrowed down to just one single and now different problem. Using the for loop iteration variable to get the array element. See the full code below and the current error message. NOTE!!! if I remove the for loop and just manually specify the element number, everything works.

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Taco help menu', add_help=True)
parser.add_argument('-s', '--start', dest='start', action='store', help='enter the starting <value>', metavar='<value>')
parser.add_argument('-e', '--end', dest='end', action='store', help='enter the ending <value>', metavar='<value>')
results = parser.parse_args()

arguments=[results.start,results.end]

print (arguments[0])
print (arguments[1])
print (results.start)
print (results.end)

for x in arguments:
    if arguments[x] is not None: // <-- This line seems to be the issue now. arguments[x] not working.
        print ('CLI set')
    else:
        print ('Default config')
```

Here is the current error message I am getting:

```
user@taco# python3 program.py -s 100 -e 1000
100
1000
100
1000
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "program.py", line 38, in <module>
    if arguments[x] is not None:
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

*** UPDATE ***

By the way... this (below) technically solves the problem by just avoiding it in the first place haha. Of course now every time a new argument is added to the program, this list has to be manually added too. Not ideal. Would still like to figure out this for loop issue.

```
if results.start:
    start = results.start
if results.end:
    end = results.end
```

Now when you set the argument via the CLI, it prefers that value over the one in the config file.

Comment: What do you mean by "print the variable names"? Can you give a [mcve], including simple `argparse` code , and a sample command line, and what you'd like to print out for that command line?

Comment: arguments[x] returns the integer value in that array, ie start = 100 for example. I also need the actual string stored in the array, ie "start" to for use in the if statement above to check to see if the argument passed from argparse is set. See my updates above.

Comment: What string? If `arguments[0]` is 0, and `arguments[1]` is some other number, where in `arguments` does that string live? Meanwhile, your edit doesn't make that any clearer, and still doesn't provide any of the things I asked for, still isn't anywhere near a [mcve], and still isn't answerable.

Comment: Are you hoping the user can set arbitrary arguments by name? If they are just entering numbers (like 100) as the arguments, then these do not have any string/variable name associated with them, except what you chose to save them to.

Comment: There is no string in the list. A variable is not a string. Python objects have no knowledge of the variables that reference them. And that is a good design, for at least the fact that it is preventing you from going down the rabbit hole you are about to try to dig yourself into. If you want to associate a string with a value, the ideal data structure would likely be a `dict`

Comment: IOW you list doesn't contain variables, it contains objects.

Comment: See my update above where I include some additional code and a little bit more explanation. Start reading at ** EXAMPLE **

Comment: I have since made one additional update and have fixed most of the issue I think. Just having difficulty now with the array element using the for loop. See hopefully final update above. Hopefully more clear now.

Comment: For the last update—why do you even _need_ to do that? Why not just keep `results` around and use `results.start` and `results.end`?

Comment: Meanwhile, please don't structure your question as a long string of "UPDATE" sections. If anyone wants to see the history of the question for some reason, they can click on the "edited 2 mins ago". For everyone else, the question should be in a form that can be readily understood and answered as-is.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access a list with a value rather then a key, which could work in rare cases. Since for is a for each loop you are already iterating over the items inside the list.

This is wrong, x does not mean the key rather the item itself, if you a trying to write a "regular" for loop you would need to iterate over the length of the list and not the items to get each key, as you would in any other language:

```
Wrong:
for x in arguments:
    if arguments[x] is not None:

foreach
for x in arguments:
    if x:
        # Do stuff
    else:
        # Do other stuff
```

An appraoch like this might be easier.

```
import argparse


def import_config():
    return {
        "start": 10,
        "end": 100
    }


def do_stuff(start, end):
    print(start, end)


if __name__=="__main__":
    config = import_config()
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("-s", type=int, dest="start", default=config["start"])
    parser.add_argument("-e", type=int, dest="end", default=config["end"])
    args = parser.parse_args()

    do_stuff(args.start, args.end)
```

Answer (score 0):

In python when the user enters nothing in a input() which is the cli input i assume you must be using, the default value stored in it is ''.
So I would simply suggest checking if the variable is not set to None type or empty string and that can be done like this.

```
if start:
   #logic here
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Why did anyone upvote this? It's almost entirely nonsense. The type of `''` is `str`, not `None` (which isn't even a type), or even `NoneType`. Also, the OP said he's using `argparse`. That's a library to parse command-line arguments. Which are not the same thing as `input()`.

Comment: Sorry, the answer I wrote was not what I meant... I made the changes. :)